# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core' When importing openai python sdk to renpy

Tags: python, openai-api, pydantic, renpy

when importing openai python sdk in a renpy project

```
init python:           

    from openai import OpenAI
```

This error appear

```
I'm sorry, but an uncaught exception occurred.  While running game code:   File "game/script.rpy", line 22, in script     init python:   File "game/script.rpy", line 27, in <module>     from openai import OpenAI ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core'
```

The full traceback can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/m2CMsAFL)

I installed the Openai library using
`pip install --target game/python-packages openai`

I tried installing the pydantic core and pydantic-package via pip

`pip install --target game/python-packages pydantic-core`

`pip install --target game/python-packages pydantic`

I also tried deleting all the packages and installing them again but still no avail
It's only an issue with the openai package
the other installed packages work fine

I can see both  pydantic and pydantic core package in the python-packages folder
The Pydantic-core version is `2.16.3`
and the pydantic version is `2.6.4`